# How to sort a multidimesional array with respect to another multidimensional array in C, C++ or Fortran for billion points quickly?

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array, fortran

I have a data set A as:

```
cx1, cy1,cz1
cx2, cy2,cz2
cx3, cy3,cz3
cx4, cy4,cz4
cx5, cy5,cz5
cx6, cy6,cz6
cx7, cy7,cz7
cx8, cy8,cz8
.................
```

Here c stands for coordinate, (x,y,z) for direction, and the number is for point indices.

Let us have another data set as B as:

```
cx7, cy7,cz7,vx7, vy7, vz7
cx3, cy3,cz3,vx3, vy3, vz3
cx8, cy8,cz8,vx8, vy8, vz8
cx2, cy2,cz2,vx2, vy2, vz2
cx5, cy5,cz5,vx5, vy5, vz5
cx4, cy4,cz4,vx4, vy4, vz4
cx1, cy1,cz1,vx1, vy1, vz1
cx6, cy6,cz6,vx6, vy6, vz6
.......................................
```

Here, v is a quantity let's say velocity and as we see the order is random.

How can I sort B data in terms of A data in the fastest way keeping the same correspondence of coordinate and velocity in data set B as the number of data points are in billion?

Comment: Such a broad multi-language question probably won't be welcomed too well.

Comment: @VladimirF - I think it's a fine question. I was about to write a suggested solution.

Comment: @selbie Go ahead... I think C++ (or C) would normally suffice and I write it as a Fortran programmer.

Comment: Can you make the question more specific? What are the types? Is it integers? How big? Or are they floats? Will it run on cpu or gpu?

Comment: I'm more curious if he wants the solution in C or Fortran.

Comment: Do you mean that every cx, cy, cz set in the second array appears somewhere in the first array, and that is the basis for sorting the second array?

Comment: The short answer is "use a hash table".  Before I write up an answer, I'd like to know if the OP can accept a C++ solution. It's harder in C, but can be done.

Comment: This would probably be rather slow to execute, but quick to write (in Fortran): `B = B(A(:,1),:)`.  And for a billion points something might break ...

Comment: Is memory a problem? Just having the data sets in memory seems to require more than 40G depending on data types. What is your memory budget for this? **BTW: What data types are these sets based on?**

Comment: How are data stored? Arrays? Or can any container type be selected? And how do data get into the system?

Comment: (a) Does each element in A appear exactly once in B? If not, can it appear more than once? Can it appear less than once? (b) Does each element in B (identified by “cxn, cyn,czn” for some ) appear exactly once in A? If not, can it appear more than once? Can it appear less than once? (c) What does “sort B data in terms of A data” mean? Does it mean that, if some element in B is identified by “cxn, cyn, czn”, it short be sorted by the value of n, i.e., the position of “cxn, cyn, czn” in A?

Comment: (d) Is A ordered in any way, such as by one of the coordinates first, then another, then the third?

Comment: It is wise to avoid a problem in the first place. If A and B contain exactly the same points, why are they in a different order anyway? If B is newer, why wasn’t it kept in the same order as A? If A is new (so the points existed, because they exist in B, but A has been put into a new order), why wasn’t the new order applied to B instead of prepared in a separate array A?

Comment: Why do you need to sort the data? Is it for presentation, to draw on a graph, several graphs or for looking up?  There are different techniques depending on the why.  Just sorting may not be the most efficient way of accessing the data afterwards.  Have you considered sticking it in a database?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: Hash table.**

If this was C++, this would be easy.  But you're on your own for a hash table implementation in pure C or Fortran.

Create a hash table that maps from "Point" to the array index in set A.  That is {cx1, cy1, cz1} would map to index 0 and {cx8, cy8, cz8} would map to index 7.  You'll need to implement a custom hash function which could be as simple as `cx XOR cy XOR cz`.

Using any sort algorithm (such as the built in qsort in C or std::sort in C++), sort the items in B.  In your comparator function that decides if a particular item is greater than or less than the other, look up the cx,cy,cz point in the hash table that you made from the items in A to get the original index location of both points.

Comment: I don't understand the need for `qsort`. If the hash table lookup can give the index then traditional sorting seems like extra work

Comment: @4386427: Given some element in B, we might identify it corresponds to the element in position n in A, but that does not mean it will go into position n in the sorted B, because B might not contain all the elements of A or might contain some elements multiple times. Although the example shown in the question has a 1-1 correspondence between A and B, this is not stated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, it's not clearly stated that a 1-1 correspondence between A and B exists but it the example strongly suggests that. Further if a specific x,y,z from B isn't present in A, where should it be placed (aka what should a compare function return). Similar problems would arise if a x,y,z was present more than one time. So to me it seems that 1-1 with unique elements must be a requirement. But again ... it's true that OP never states that clearly. Just like many other things that ain't clear in the question.

Comment: If the points in "set B" aren't 1:1 with the points in "Set A" and the goal is to sort B by closeness to points in A - then the correct data structure is a kd-tree.  Given the OP's lack of detail and low rep score, I'm not rushing to sketch out a solution.